# Linux: How to indetify what consumes 35G of system memory

Tags: linux, memory, rss, ps

currently the processes of one of usr systems are consuming 6,5G RSS:

```
root@system:~# ps aux | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum +=$6} END {print sum/1024, "MB"}'
6575.42 MB
root@system:~#
```

If I run `free -m` it's telling me that 41G (43,9G - 2,1G) of memory are currently used:

```
root@system:~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          64402       43952       18322           0        2127       19735
Swap:        131070         129      130941
root@system:~#
```

So **I miss ~35G of system memory**!

Normally I expect a higher sum of rss because of the shared segments (not considered by ps)?!

How can I identify what is consuming my memory?

A reboot of the system is scheduled for the 6th...

Answer (score 0):

You can have a clear view of the system process and the related resources used installing the `htop` tool.

You can summarize the memory usage with the following command:

```bsh
ps aux --sort -rss
```

Refer to the following link for further information on the topic:
http://alvinalexander.com/linux/unix-linux-process-memory-sort-ps-command-cpu

Comment: This is not useful! Even using `ps aux --sort -rss` shows 6,5G RSS used!

Comment: Try with `htop`

Comment: Same result using `htop`! :-/ If I sumarize the RSS i end up at ~6,5G.